# How do I prevent linked modules from losing their association in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a fork of the Spring-Integration project and I'm creating a client to test it. I have both gradle modules in an Intellij project, however I'm having an annoying issue. I link my standalone client to the proper spring-integration modules by creating dependencies and the project works. However, every time I add a new dependency to my test client these linkages get wiped out after doing a gradle refresh. Is there some way to preserve them so I don't have to add them over and over?

Answer (score 0):

For the Gradle-based modules in IDE **always** use `build.gradle` file for managing dependencies. For such projects IDE provides the same experience as you would build it by Gradle from command line.

So if you plan using Gradle, transform the client project into Gradle module and add it as [project dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
}
```